# Geodesic equation proof confusing me

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differentiation, geodesics

I was looking through this proof and have no idea where the $u$ comes from. Any help is appreciated.

This is from [here](http://physicspages.com/tag/geodesic-equation/); I want to know how they got from eqn 5 to eqn 6.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The step between (4) and (5) is an application of the chain rule.  If you follow each of the terms carefully, you can see that
$$u^t = \frac{dt}{d\tau}$$
I think one of the reasons it's confusing is that in step (5) for some reason they have both $u^t$ and $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ present in the equation at the same time, even though they are the same quantity.  I think they were trying to make the application of the chain rule clearer, but I don't think they succeeded.

Comment: XD this is true. Much obliged.